# TweenLite on CocoonJS

Tags: gsap, cocoonjs

Today I started exporting my game into CocoonJS and soon realized that TweenLite from GreenSock simply doesn't work for some reason. Basically the code just stops running as soon as it encounters a TweenLite function - the error console stays silent.

Can someone recommend a good javascript tweening engine that is compatible with CocoonJS? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I've tested and I use Tween.js by sole in GitHub at https://github.com/sole/tween.js/. There may be no better than TweenLite, but it still is fast and fluid (tested on iPhone 3GS and Android Samsung Galaxy S3 ...). In addition, Tween.js is licensed under the MIT, where you can put ads and in-app purchases in your apps free of charge. Unlike TweenLite which you have to pay a professional license ($ 50 / year).

Comment: Thanks I found that CreateJs/TweenJS works well. It also turns out that TweenLite will run on Cocoon - but there is some collision with pixi.js that I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: We're using TweenLite with the Pixi.js on CocoonJS and not seeing any issues here. Maybe try upgrading to 1.5.1 which was just released today.